# Conditional link with fallback to another element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does any method exist, or is there any clean way to write a conditional link method that accept a block and would fall back to another kind of element, rendering the same content in the block ?

Let's say something like ..

```
<%= link_fallback_if condition?, some_path do %>
  <img src="somepicture.png" />
  <p>somelabel</p>
  <p>someanothercontent</p>
<% end %>
```

If the condition is true it would provide:

```
<a href="/someaction">
  <img src="somepicture.png" />
  <p>somelabel</p>
  <p>someanothercontent</p>
</a>
```

.. and would fall back to:

```
<div class="disabled">
  <img src="somepicture.png" />
  <p>somelabel</p>
  <p>someanothercontent</p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper method similar to the following:

```
def link_to_or_div(condition, *args, &block)
  if condition
    link_to(*args, &block)
  else
    content_tag(:div, *args, &block)
  end
end
```